# How to transform list of tuples into a tuple?

Tags: python

How can I transform

```
[(212, u'comment', 0L), (205, u'main', 0L)]
```

into this?

```
(0L, 0L)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> data = [(212, u'comment', 0L), (205, u'main', 0L)]
>>> tuple(x[2] for x in data)
(0L, 0L)
```

Or another method...

```
>>> zip(*data)   # just showing what zip(*data) does
[(212, 205), (u'comment', u'main'), (0L, 0L)]
>>> zip(*data)[2]
(0L, 0L)
```

Using `itertools.imap()` and `operator.itemgetter()`...

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> tuple(imap(itemgetter(2), data))
(0L, 0L)
```